# How to upload video to youtube from firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, youtube-api

Is there any way to upload videos from the firebase cloud function to youtube?

 If possible and if we upload 2 Gb date using firebase cloud function is it charge for 2 Gb data transfer change $0.12*2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Nodejs client library for the Youtube API. I recommend you to go through the [Quickstart for this client library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs) and follow the [YouTube API Samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/youtube) where you could find an example on how to upload a video:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Usage: node upload.js PATH_TO_VIDEO_FILE
 */

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');

// initialize the Youtube API library
const youtube = google.youtube('v3');

// very basic example of uploading a video to youtube
async function runSample(fileName) {
  // Obtain user credentials to use for the request
  const auth = await authenticate({
    keyfilePath: path.join(__dirname, '../oauth2.keys.json'),
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
    ],
  });
  google.options({auth});

  const fileSize = fs.statSync(fileName).size;
  const res = await youtube.videos.insert(
    {
      part: 'id,snippet,status',
      notifySubscribers: false,
      requestBody: {
        snippet: {
          title: 'Node.js YouTube Upload Test',
          description: 'Testing YouTube upload via Google APIs Node.js Client',
        },
        status: {
          privacyStatus: 'private',
        },
      },
      media: {
        body: fs.createReadStream(fileName),
      },
    },
    {
      // Use the `onUploadProgress` event from Axios to track the
      // number of bytes uploaded to this point.
      onUploadProgress: evt => {
        const progress = (evt.bytesRead / fileSize) * 100;
        readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
        readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
        process.stdout.write(`${Math.round(progress)}% complete`);
      },
    }
  );
  console.log('\n\n');
  console.log(res.data);
  return res.data;
}

if (module === require.main) {
  const fileName = process.argv[2];
  runSample(fileName).catch(console.error);
}

module.exports = runSample;
```

In regard of the pricing, the Youtube API is free but your charges will depend on the [Firebase plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) you choose.